# Mixing annotation based pointcuts with method signature based pointcuts in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a method that looks like:

```
@Log
@Override
public Item update(Item item) {
   ...
}
```

Now I have two aspects that target the same method. One via the @Log annotation and one via the method signature. It seems that only one of the aspects is getting triggered. How do I do this properly? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: You should show code of your aspects.

Comment: Out of the two , which one works ? If you remove/comment-out the one that works , is the other advice working as expected ?

Comment: They should both be triggered, there is no limitation there and it also is not bad practice. The problem must be your aspect code or Spring aspect configuration. So please show the code you are asking questions about. Please also learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.